# Expressing the spectral radius as a function of the matrix size

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra, spectral-radius

Currently, I am working with a (non-symmetric) discretization matrix $A$ coming from a [convection-diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation) problem without elimination of boundary conditions. Regarding the SOR algorithm, I have to express the number of iterations until convergence as a function of the matrix size $N$. Looking for literature on the internet, I found that this number of iterations is directly related to the spectral radius of iteration matrix, $\rho(B_{SOR})$.

However, this is where I get stuck. I see the relationship between the spectral radius and the eigenvalues of the matrix. But I can't seem to find any relationship between $\rho(B_{SOR})$ and matrix size $N$. Can anyone please help with finding this relation?

Comment: It might be helpful to write out your matrix $A$ and also your PDE.

Comment: Same notation for matrix and its size is not wonderful.

Comment: @CheeHan the PDE is $-\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=(x^2+y^2)\sin(xy)+(x+y)\cos(xy)$. I have also written out matrix $A$, which is quite complex to write down here, but then what would I be looking for?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks for replying! What do you mean with your comment?

Comment: Yeah I have no idea, but I thought you writing out the matrix $A$ and the PDEs might help other people in figuring it out. Do you have a strong reason to suspect that what you wanted is true?

Comment: @CheeHan I don't see the relationship myself, but it is part of a university homework question, so I guess should be true ;)

Comment: @hans15 As you increase the number of discretization points, you obtain matrices of increasing dimension, while preserving the basic structure. So, for each of these matrices, you can compute the spectral radius. You can then plot N vs. spectral radius and try to guess the relation performing for instance soime poilynomial fit of the data (if it seems polynomial).